# Notification icons are not being displayed on the status bar

Tags: notification-bar, 8.0-oreo, notification-icons, 8.1-oreo

You can see that I have notifications in WhatsApp and Messages app but the notifications icons are not visible on the status bar. I have searched through the settings but couldn't find a way.

**Device = Oppo F9**
**Version = 8.1 Oreo**

[image: picture]

Comment: Notifications can be permitted at the global, but also application level. Have you checked all their individual settings? Also, the order and placement of your status bar icons could be altered in different ways. Are you using a 3rd party launcher that regulates their placement or masks them altogether?

Comment: Yes, i checked individual settings. 2. status bar icons cant be altered, because Android does not allow users/developers to customize status bar. i am not using any launcher.